# Escanear mais de uma string

Tags: c, string, scanf

Em C posso escanear mais de um *string* como se faz com inteiros?

Tipo:

```
scanf("%s %s", pal1, pal2);
```

Comment: A pergunta é de C ou C#?

Comment: C msm. Desculpas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char pal1[100], pal2[100];
    scanf("%s %s", pal1, pal2);
    printf("%s - %s", pal1, pal2);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/3x4hJG). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/bbqttlml-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Console/ReadTwoStrings.c).

Answer (score -1):

Cara, scanf é de C,
Em C#:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1

Exemplo da microsoft:

```
using System;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      Console.Clear();

      DateTime dat = DateTime.Now;

      Console.WriteLine("\nToday is {0:d} at {0:T}.", dat);
      Console.Write("\nPress any key to continue... ");
      Console.ReadLine();
   }
}
// The example displays output like the following:
//     Today is 10/26/2015 at 12:22:22 PM.
//     
//     Press any key to continue...
```

Comment: A pergunta já deixou claro que é em C, sua resposta ficou fora de contexto

Comment: Ontem ele tinha citado C# no título, por isso coloquei a resposta.

Comment: Sim, no corpo da pergunta, mas nas tags tava C, tava confuso: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/238214/1